# How does the chamber pressure affect the performance of a Rocket Engine?

Tags: rockets, engines, pressure

I am under the assumption that higher chamber pressure results in increase in exhaust velocity. Is this true?

Comment: I first read it "camembert pressure" and it was very strange. I think you meant to say chamber (please correct the title and the body of your post)

Comment: Increasing the pressure of the fuel increases its enthalpy (the energy content of the fuel). The Isp is a function of the enthalpy of the fuel and the efficiency of the engine which is given by the injector, chamber and nozzle. The biggest advantage of a higher pressure is that you can increase the nozzle expansion ratio during atmospheric flight which greatly increases efficiency or allows for a smaller/lighter nozzle at the same expansion ratio. That's why upper stage engines tend to have lower chamber pressures.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is absolutely true.

[image]

On this graph you can see the ISPs (aka exhaust velocity) at different mixture ration and chamber pressure.

The higher the pressure the higher the velocity and thus delta/v per unit of fuel.

A few other parameters come into play:

- The shape of the nozzle
- The pressure ratio between the combustion chamber and the outside (the higher the ambiant pressure the lower the ratio the lower the exhaust velocity)

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/ISP-as-a-function-of-propellant-mixture-ratio-and-chamber-pressure-for-nitrous-oxide-and_fig4_305620863